# О неумехах

Tags: орфография, этимология

Заинтересовало слово "неумеха" Во-первых, как правильно: неумЁха или неумЕха, а во-вторых, интересно, от какого слова оно произошло: "не умный" или "неумелый"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НЕУМЕХА - (прост.) - тот, кто всё делает плохо или не умеет делать ничего.

Словарь Резниченко (2010 г.) дает два варианта: неумЕха и неумЁха.

Схема образования: не уметь - неумеха, суффикс Х, сравнить: растерять - растеряха.